# IndexErrror:list index out of range

Tags: python

I have written a small function that would give me a reduced vector from a matrix using the `LLL` algorithm using the `olll` module.

The function is to return a reduced vector from a matrix `m`:

```
python
def orthocomp(matr):
    return olll.reduction(matr[:,np.shape(m)[0]+1:-1],0.75)[0]
orthocomp(np.array([[1,1,1],[-1,0,2],[3,5,6]]))
```

and when i want to test it putting the matrix as you can see in the code it shows me the error message bellow, i tried to read the traceback but no results.

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I'm not super familiar with this library, but I have a hunch that it's the `[0]` index giving you a problem. Can you 1) show which line the error is occurring on (should be given by the compiler/error message), and 2) add a `print` statement to see if the `olll.reduction` method is returning an empty list?

Comment: the error is occuring in the return line as the message is `----> 3 orthocomp(np.array([[1,1,1],[-1,0,2],[3,5,6]]))` also `----> 2     return olll.reduction(matr[:,np.shape(m)[1]+1:-1],0.75)[1]`, i have tested this library before working with it and it works by writting the same function without the slicing part `[:,np.shape(m)[0]+1:-1]`which it gives a reduced matrix but for this case i want a a reduced vector, i changed the `[0]`index but the same thing is happening